# Using JavaScript direction API, need mix direction instruction in walking and transit

Tags: javascript, google-maps

am going to design one software. I want to use javascript api for map service. But I could not find mix direction using tutorial.

- I would select source and destination using google place search box. (0K)
- by default transit will be selected (OK)
- direction will be displayed with instruction (OK)
- Direction should be included both walking and transit. But I can`t implement this. Could you please help me on this part.

Basically, I need support to show both walking and transit instruction to reach destination.

Answer (score 0):

Here is 2 requests generating directions for random cities, make sure to copy your api key.

walking directions

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Toronto&destination=Montreal&avoid=highways&mode=walking&key=YOURAPIKEY

driving directions

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Toronto&destination=Montreal&avoid=highways&mode=driving&key=YOURAPIKEY

if you want to do it using the JS api I coded a small example, paste your api key, you can change travel modes, walking and driving.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
      * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      var map;
      var directions;

  function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
      zoom: 8
    });
    directions = new google.maps.DirectionsService
    directions.route({
      origin: 'Tokyo',
      destination: 'Yokohama',
      region: "Ja",
      travelMode: 'TRANSIT',
      unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL
    }, (route)=> console.log(route))
  }
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBsYuTQdeFRaWzydcZnD6Dk39qCqDHtuDU&callback=initMap"
        async defer></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. 
But could you give example with TRANSIT travelMode in any places in Japan

Comment: Sure! I edited the example above to include to random cities I googled around Tokyo.